# An Action Method is been Called without specifying it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want a popup with id `exampleModalCenter` to be displayed
but it is redirecting to path localhost:../Employee/Edit .. which is also not defined

Below is my Controller:

```
using AJAX.Models;
using AJAX.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;

namespace AJAX.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ShashankTrainingContext _dbcontext;
        public EmployeeController()
        {
            _dbcontext = new ShashankTrainingContext();
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetAllEmployee()
        {
            var products = _dbcontext.EmployeeInfoFromDb
       .FromSqlRaw(string.Format("exec GetEmployeeData"))
       .ToList();
            var employees = (from emp in products
                             select new EmployeeInfoViewModel
                             {
                                 Id = emp.Id,
                                 FirstName = emp.FirstName,
                                 LastName = emp.LastName,
                                 Dob = emp.Dob != null ? emp.Dob.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") : "",
                                 Doj = emp.Doj != null ? emp.Doj.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") : "",
                                 Salary = emp.Salary,
                                 Gender = emp.Gender,
                                 GenderId = emp.GenderId,
                                 Department = emp.Department,
                                 DepartmentId = emp.DepartmentId,
                                 Designation = emp.Designation,
                                 DesignationId = emp.DesignationId,
                                 ManagerId = emp.ManagerId != null ? emp.ManagerId.ToString() : "",

                             }).ToList();

            //var empInfoList = _dbcontext.EmployeeInfos.ToList();
            //var employees = (from emp in _dbcontext.EmployeeInfos
            //                 join gen in _dbcontext.Genders on emp.GenderId equals gen.Id
            //                 join dept in _dbcontext.Departments on emp.DepartmentId equals dept.Id
            //                 join designation in _dbcontext.Designations on emp.DesignationId equals designation.Id
            //                 into empl
            //                 from e in empl.DefaultIfEmpty()
            //
            //                 select new EmployeeInfoViewModel
            //                 {
            //                     Id = emp.Id,
            //                     FirstName = emp.FirstName,
            //                     LastName = emp.LastName,
            //                     Dob = emp.Dob != null ? emp.Dob.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "",
            //                     Doj = emp.Doj != null ? emp.Doj.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "",
            //                     Salary = emp.Salary,
            //                     Gender = gen.Code,
            //                     Department = dept.Code,
            //                     Designation = emp.Designation.Code,
            //                     ManagerId = emp.ManagerId != null ? emp.ManagerId.ToString() : "",
            //                 }).ToList();
            if (employees.Any())
            {
                foreach (var emp in employees)
                {
                    var skills = _dbcontext.EmployeeSkillsMappings.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == emp.Id).Select(x => x.Skill.Code).ToList();
                    if (skills.Any())
                    {
                        emp.EmployeeSkills = skills.ToArray();// string.Join(',', skills.ToArray());
                    }
                    else emp.EmployeeSkills = new string[0];
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult(employees);
        }


        public JsonResult DeleteEmployee(int Id)
        {
            using (var transaction = _dbcontext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var employeeSkills = new List<EmployeeSkillsMapping>();
                    //            var EmployeeSkillsMapping = _dbcontext.EmployeeSkillsMappings.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == empId);
                    var employeeinfo = new EmployeeInfo() { Id = Id };
                    

                    _dbcontext.EmployeeInfos.Remove(employeeinfo);
                    _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Commit();
                    return Json(new { isValid = true, Id });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    transaction.Rollback();

                    return Json(new { isValid = false, Id });
                }
            }
        }


        [Route("Employee/Create/{Id?}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int? Id)
        {
           
            List<int> empSkillIds = new List<int>();
            var employeeInfoViewModel = new EmployeeInfoViewModel();
            employeeInfoViewModel.drpSelectedSkills = new List<SelectListItem>();
            employeeInfoViewModel.drpSkills = new List<SelectListItem>();
            if (Id.HasValue)
            {
                var emp = _dbcontext.EmployeeInfos.Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
                employeeInfoViewModel.Id = emp.Id;
                employeeInfoViewModel.FirstName = emp.FirstName;
                employeeInfoViewModel.LastName = emp.LastName;
                employeeInfoViewModel.Doj = emp.Doj.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                // DOjdate = emp.Doj ?? DOjdate;
                var employeeExistingSkills = _dbcontext.EmployeeSkillsMappings.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == Id);
                int counter = 0;

                employeeInfoViewModel.Salary = emp.Salary;
                employeeInfoViewModel.DepartmentId = emp.DepartmentId.Value;
                employeeInfoViewModel.DesignationId = emp.DesignationId.Value;
                employeeInfoViewModel.GenderId = emp.GenderId;
                employeeInfoViewModel.ManagerId = emp.ManagerId.ToString() ?? "";
            }
            LoadEntity(employeeInfoViewModel);
            return View(employeeInfoViewModel);
        }
        private void LoadEntity(EmployeeInfoViewModel employeeInfoViewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Department> departments = new List<Department>();
                departments.Add(new Department { Id = 0, Code = "PleaseSelect", Description = "Please Select" });

                departments.AddRange(_dbcontext.Departments);
                List<Designation> designations = new List<Designation>();
                designations.Add(new Designation { Id = 0, Code = "PleaseSelect", Name = "Please Select" });
                designations.AddRange(_dbcontext.Designations);
                List<Gender> genders = new List<Gender>();
                genders.AddRange(_dbcontext.Genders);
                employeeInfoViewModel.drpSkills = _dbcontext.WhSkills.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Code, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();

                if (employeeInfoViewModel.Id != 0)
                {
                    var employeeSkills = _dbcontext.EmployeeSkillsMappings.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeInfoViewModel.Id).ToList();
                    if (employeeSkills.Any())
                        employeeInfoViewModel.drpSkills.RemoveAll(x => employeeSkills.Exists(z => z.SkillId.ToString() == x.Value));
                }
                var skills = _dbcontext.WhSkills.
               Select(x =>
                new WhSkillsViewModel
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Code = x.Code,
                    Checked = false,
                }).Distinct().ToList();
                if (employeeInfoViewModel.Id != 0)
                {
                    var employeeSkills = _dbcontext.EmployeeSkillsMappings.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeInfoViewModel.Id).ToList();
                    if (employeeSkills.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var sKill in skills)
                        {
                            if (employeeSkills.Any(x => x.SkillId == sKill.Id))
                                sKill.Checked = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ViewBag.Skills = skills;

                //    employeeInfoViewModel.SelectedSkills.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "ABC" });
                List<EmployeeInfo> employeeInfo = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
                employeeInfo.AddRange(_dbcontext.EmployeeInfos);
                ViewBag.EmployeeInfo = employeeInfo;
                ViewBag.departments = departments;
                ViewBag.designations = designations;
                ViewBag.genders = genders;
                ViewBag.EmployeeId = employeeInfoViewModel.Id;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        public JsonResult GetSKills(int? employeeId)
        {
            var skills = _dbcontext.WhSkills.
                Select(x =>
                 new WhSkillsViewModel
                 {
                     Id = x.Id,
                     Code = x.Code,
                     Checked = false,
                 }).Distinct().ToList();
            if (employeeId.HasValue)
            {
                var employeeSkills = _dbcontext.EmployeeSkillsMappings.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeId.Value).ToList();
                if (employeeSkills.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var sKill in skills)
                    {
                        if (employeeSkills.Any(x => x.SkillId == sKill.Id))
                            sKill.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult(skills);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddEmployee(EmployeeInfoViewModel obj)
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    AddOrEditEmployeeInfo(obj);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return Json(new { success = false,responseText="There was some problem while processing the request" });
                }

            }
            return Json(new { success = true,responseText="Employee Added/Updated Successfully" });
        }

        private async Task<bool> AddOrEditEmployeeInfo(EmployeeInfoViewModel obj)
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
            var IsEmployeeToEdit = false;
            var empInfoList =await _dbcontext.EmployeeInfos.ToListAsync();
            var employeeinfo = new EmployeeInfo();
            List<EmployeeSkillsMapping> employeeSkillsMappings = new List<EmployeeSkillsMapping>();
            Validation validator = new Validation();
            if (!validator.CheckIfEmployeeAlreadyExist(obj, empInfoList))
            {
                if (obj.Id == 0)
                {
                    employeeinfo.FirstName = obj.FirstName;
                    employeeinfo.LastName = obj.LastName;
                    employeeinfo.Dob = DateTime.Parse(obj.Dob);
                    employeeinfo.Doj = DateTime.Parse(obj.Doj);
                    employeeinfo.GenderId = obj.GenderId;
                    employeeinfo.DepartmentId = obj.DepartmentId;
                    employeeinfo.DesignationId = obj.DesignationId;
                    employeeinfo.Salary = obj.Salary;
                    employeeinfo.ManagerId = obj.ManagerId != null ? int.Parse(obj.ManagerId) : null;
                    _dbcontext.Add(employeeinfo);
                   await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();

                }
                else
                {
                    IsEmployeeToEdit = true;
                    employeeinfo = _dbcontext.EmployeeInfos.Where(x => x.Id == obj.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    employeeinfo.FirstName = obj.FirstName;
                    employeeinfo.LastName = obj.LastName;
                    employeeinfo.GenderId = obj.GenderId;
                    employeeinfo.DepartmentId = obj.DepartmentId;
                    employeeinfo.DesignationId = obj.DesignationId;
                    employeeinfo.Salary = obj.Salary;
                    employeeinfo.ManagerId = obj.ManagerId != null ? int.Parse(obj.ManagerId) : null;
                }
               // _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                AddSkills(employeeinfo, obj, employeeSkillsMappings, IsEmployeeToEdit);
                _dbcontext.AddRange(employeeSkillsMappings);
               await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }
        private void AddSkills(EmployeeInfo employeeInfo, EmployeeInfoViewModel employeeInfoViewModel, List<EmployeeSkillsMapping> employeeSkillsMappings, bool IsEmployeeToEdit = true)
        {

            if (employeeInfoViewModel != null && employeeInfoViewModel.SelectedSkillsIds != null && employeeInfoViewModel.SelectedSkillsIds.Any())
            {
                var employeeInfoId = employeeInfoViewModel.Id;

                var ExistingEMpskillstoRemove = _dbcontext.EmployeeSkillsMappings.Where(x => x.Employee == employeeInfo).ToList();
                if (ExistingEMpskillstoRemove.Any())
                {
                    _dbcontext.EmployeeSkillsMappings.RemoveRange(ExistingEMpskillstoRemove);
                }

                foreach (var e in employeeInfoViewModel.SelectedSkillsIds)
                {
                    employeeSkillsMappings.Add(new EmployeeSkillsMapping { SkillId = e, Employee = employeeInfo });
                }

            }

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> CheckIfEmployeeExist(List<EmployeeInfoViewModel> empList)
        {
            var employeeinfos =await _dbcontext.EmployeeInfos.ToListAsync();
            var txtmessage = "";
            foreach (var emp in empList)
            {
                var employeeinfo =  employeeinfos.Where(x => x.FirstName == emp.FirstName && x.LastName == emp.LastName && x.Id != emp.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                if(employeeinfo != null) {
                    txtmessage+=$"{employeeinfo.FirstName.ToUpper()} {employeeinfo.LastName.ToUpper()}\n";
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtmessage))
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, responseText = txtmessage });
            }
            return Json(new { success = true, responseText = $"The records are valid" });
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult EditAllEmployeeInfo(List<EmployeeInfoViewModel> prm)
        {
                try
                {
                    if (prm != null)
                    { 
                        foreach (var e in prm)
                        {
                             AddOrEditEmployeeInfo(e);
                        }
                    }

                return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Records Updated Successfully" });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Records Updated Successfully" });
                }
        }

    }
    
}
```

And below is Jquery function been used:

```
$("#Save").click(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#exampleModalCenter").modal('show');
    
    $("#exampleModalCenter").modal('show');
})
```

I am expecting a Pop up but localhost:/Employee/Edit is been called and I have no such method

Comment: I'm assuming you have *other* code / HTML..  Please read [mcve].   We need to see the *relevant* code - actions such as `GetSKills`[sic] (get-s-kills?) do not appear to be relevant.  Remove/comment these from your own code to narrow down your code to *only* enough code to reproduce the issue.  Then include that code here.  The issue is most likely around the dialog itself and/or your #Save button, which you've not included.

Comment: Please provide related html code about how to trigger this popup function, Just backend code is difficult to find the solution about your case.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller isn't a factor in this.

It seems you have a button on your form with type "submit".  This will submit the form when pressed.  Change the type to "button" for it to use your `.click`.

Something like:
`<button type="button" id="Save">Save</button>`